# $f(x,y)=2 , 0<x<y<1$ Find $E(X|Y)$

Tags: probability

$f(x,y)=2 , 0<x<y<1$ Find $E(X|Y)$
Now , I found out that $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{1}{y}$
Thus, $E(X|Y)=\int_{0}^{y} x.\frac{1}{y} dx =\frac{y}{2}$
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: More correctly $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\tfrac 1y~\mathbf 1_{(0<x<y<1)}$ and $\mathsf E(X\mid Y) = \tfrac 12Y~\mathbf 1_{(0<Y<1)}$